# SelectPDF missing content after conversion

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, pdf, selectpdf

So I am using SelectPDF to convert an MVC view's html to PDF, but for some reason, a great deal of the content is missing from the PDF.

I have tested the program on other sites I have made in MVC and they work...

So as per the readme doc's recommendation, I use this code to produce a

```
SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf converter = new SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf();
SelectPdf.PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(HTMLPath);
//SelectPdf.PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(ViewHTML);

doc.Save(PDFSavePath);
doc.Close();
```

So `HTMLSave` path is the location of the HTML file created from the rendered MVC view. While `ViewHTML` contains the HTML in the form of a string.

So this is how the HTML looks (the file and the view look identical, I did double check in case the HTML was captured incorrectly):

[image: HTML]

But this is how the PDF looks:

[image: PDF]
Absolutely tragic...

Not sure if it will be helpful, but here's the HTML:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8DiACLG11oYd3p5Tzc2ZlJQLVk

Unfortunately, all the HTML is on one line thanks to the MVC View to HTML

Comment: First thing I'd do would be to remove the two style sheets from the source and run it again.  See if it actually includes the missing objects.  If it does you've narrowed it down to a CSS issue.  Go from there.

Comment: That HTML string is invalid btw. It has a `<head>` and `<body>` tags nested instead a `<form>` with what looks like some validation errors. Maybe you should look into that. Also, make sure you are linking the correct stylesheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the html/css engine used to render the page does not support vh, vw for font sizes. It's a common issue with all converters, so probably you should try to change this if you need the page converted to pdf.

Later update: it seems that there is support for vw, but not for vh. That's why the "each" words appear. They use vw in css.